# CNN cannot predict seizure states

Tags: python, keras, scipy, spectrogram

I have been stuck for while now trying to replecate a paper:

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fneur.2020.00375/full

They show pretty impressing results. I have generated 4000 .png files of each class = 16000 png total.

I have now been creating spectrogram with pyplot and scipy.signal however since i am very new to signal preproccessing i think i might have skipped an important step.

The idea is to load signal data stored in an .EDF file and provide the nescessary data transformation before feeding the convolutional neural network.

My spectrogram looks like this:

[Interical state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNtmD.png)

However none of my models is able to achieve an higher accuracy than 50%...

My CNN:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (6, 6), activation='relu',
                       input_shape=(299,299,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (6, 6), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (6, 6), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(256, (6, 6), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

Training:

```
1308/1308 [==============================] - 259s 198ms/step - loss: 1.0473 - accuracy: 0.4962 - val_loss: 1.0299 - val_accuracy: 0.5168
Epoch 3/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 261s 199ms/step - loss: 1.0371 - accuracy: 0.5010 - val_loss: 1.0388 - val_accuracy: 0.5205
Epoch 4/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 260s 199ms/step - loss: 1.0235 - accuracy: 0.5114 - val_loss: 1.0308 - val_accuracy: 0.5183
Epoch 5/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 261s 199ms/step - loss: 1.0132 - accuracy: 0.5177 - val_loss: 1.0367 - val_accuracy: 0.5217
Epoch 6/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 274s 210ms/step - loss: 1.0056 - accuracy: 0.5194 - val_loss: 1.0095 - val_accuracy: 0.5373
Epoch 7/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 323s 247ms/step - loss: 0.9936 - accuracy: 0.5248 - val_loss: 1.0243 - val_accuracy: 0.5190
Epoch 8/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 241s 184ms/step - loss: 0.9860 - accuracy: 0.5358 - val_loss: 1.0084 - val_accuracy: 0.5260
Epoch 9/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 243s 185ms/step - loss: 0.9796 - accuracy: 0.5388 - val_loss: 1.0082 - val_accuracy: 0.5364
Epoch 10/10
1308/1308 [==============================] - 238s 182ms/step - loss: 0.9712 - accuracy: 0.5395 - val_loss: 1.0246 - val_accuracy: 0.5171
```

I am using cross entropy with Adam(lr=0.0001)

I am using 4 seconds signal windows at a sambling rate of 256hz = 1024 samples.

The only denoising i have used is db6 from scipy denoising wavelet.

If i plot the signal raw data it looks like:

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6LE9.png)

Is the solution to lower / limit Y-axis on the specrogram to only focus on the lower freqeuncies or do i need to do something else?

Spectrogram code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
Fs = 256         # Define the sampling frequency,
interval = Fs        # ... the interval size,
overlap = Fs * 0.95  # ... and the overlap intervals

 denoised_series = denoise_wavelet(series, method='BayesShrink',wavelet='db6', mode='hard',rescale_sigma=True, multichannel=False, wavelet_levels=3)
    if plot_title:
        plt.title(f"{channel} : is_seizure = {patient_state} : {time_of_observation}")


    f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(denoised_series, fs=Fs, nperseg=interval, noverlap=overlap)
                         
    plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10 * np.log10(Sxx), cmap='jet', shading='auto')
    plt.axis('off')
```

window function which im using in a forloop enumeration:

```
def get_window(channel, start_index, data, size = 4, overlap = 0, is_sezure = False, frequency = 256):
    if(is_sezure):
        overlap = 2
    else:
        overlap = overlap
    
    start = start_index * (size - overlap) * frequency
    end = start + (size * frequency)

    date_timestamp = ""

    try:
        date_timestamp = (datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=data['timestamp'][start]/1000)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    except:
        date_timestamp = "datetime cannot be converted"
    
    return [data[channel][start:end].tolist(), date_timestamp]
```

Comment: CNN lies so much. It's hard to trust anything they say anymore :(

Comment: mynetwork or the paper :D ?

Comment: Do I get you right that you simulate the data? For some reason I cannot access their shared data: http://physionet.mit.edu/physiobank/database/chbmit/

In general there could be many mistakes.. I would suggest to check out some kaggle epileptic seizure prediction challenges and have a look at the notebooks there: 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/seizure-detection. Those solutions will definitely work and you could start from there

Comment: I am trying to do image classification using signal data. Haven't found any except for a few papers. But i am currently no where near the same scores that the provide i their papers. I have done the following read edf file --> convert to dataframe --> add class col --> insert classes based on timestamps provided --> used my rolling window on the different classes in the df --> for each window provided wavelet denoising --> created spectrogram from the denoised signal

Comment: Did you try training the model for a lot more than 10 epochs?

Comment: yes i have used fit with 10 epochs about 3 times now so 30 epochs. I'm current trying resnet152 with all layers trainable for 50 epochs. How many epochs would you recommend before reconfigurering the model ?

Comment: I am still achieving a maximum of 58% acc i have tried appyling a lowpass filter to the EEG signal. Found out that np.log10 did not work well for EEG with this low power. Any ideas of where to go from here?